# What happens when the application crashes during an execution of LevelDB batch?

Tags: transactions, atomic, leveldb

It is mentioned in the [LevelDB Documentation](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/index.md) that write batch is capable of providing atomicity for multiple operations. Yet, I just want to know what happens if the the application crashes during an execution of a write batch. Will it rollback all the changes or will it partially commit the changes?

I am referring to a scenario as below where it takes some time for the batch to complete its execution. (Code is written in Java using [LevelDBJNI](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni))

```
WriteBatch batch = db.createWriteBatch();

    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        batch.put(("key "+Integer.toString(i)).getBytes(),("value "+Integer.toString(i)).getBytes());
    }

    System.out.println("Batch Filled");

    db.write(batch); //takes around 5s -- what if system crashes here??
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteBatch guarantees that either all or nothing ends up on the disk.  That's in case of process crash. In case of file system crash - power loss - there are no such guarantee I think.